# QEMU wrapper script for labelprinter driver not working

Tags: qemu

I am trying to get a i386 raster binary for CUPS to work on a Raspberry Pi 3b.
The driver is shipped with a 32bit raster script called `rastertort58_80`
This file is placed in `/usr/lib/cups/filter`, but I have renamed it to `rastertort58_80.x86`

I have placed this QEMU wrapper script in its place:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/etc/qemu-binfmt/i386 qemu-i386 /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertort58_80.x86 "$@"
```

I placed all the necessary shared libraries (i386) in `/etc/qemu-binfmt/i386`.

I can run this script from commandline without any errors, but when I do a printjob to CUPS I get the following error in `/var/log/cups/error_log`:

```
/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertort58_80.x86: error while loading shared libraries: libgnutls-deb0.so.28: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Problem solved. It was a file permission issue